# How to not exit from a called batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch file which calls another batch file.
The external batch is mine, the internal isn't.

The external batch is called from Java application:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + batchFileName, null, new File(batchFileDir));
```

The internal batch is called from the external batch:

```
call C:\anotherBatch.bat <fileWithCommandsForBatch
pause
```

The problem is that the internal batch finishes when the external batch finishes.
I want that the user will still be able to run commands of its own on the internal batch.

If I run the same commands of "fileWithCommandsForBatch" manually from cmd, 
the internal batch is still alive.

How can I keep the internal batch alive after the external batch finishes its job?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the different ways you call both batches and what it does in each case. I am having difficulty following your description.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added more information about the external and internal batch. Please tell me if you need any more information.

Comment: So the problem is due to the redirect into the batch file? Can you change anotherBatch.bat to take fileWithCommandsForBatch as a parameter and read the contents of that file? You may have to read up on how Java handles stdin and stdout with `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: The internal batch(anotherBatch.bat) is not mine and I cannot change or request changes for it. I can change my java application and the external batch which calls the internal. The purpose of the redirection is to interact with the internal batch, which needs to get a list of commands to do its job.

Comment: What if you call external batch to create the fileWIthCommandsForBatch, then call (again from Java) the internal batch, redirecting stdin correctly? Relying on command-line-style redirection in a headless process is fraught..

Comment: You gave me a good lead. Now I am calling the interal batch from Java. But I cannot figure out how to communicating with this internal batch(give it commands) after it started to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want users to be able to append to the standard input from `fileWithCommandsForBatch` by manually typing within the command window, see ["Prepend to stdin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081642/prepend-to-stdin#13089652). (Your Java program would not be involved.) In your external batch, you might get code like

```
(
type fileWithCommandsForBatch
more
) | call C:\anotherBatch.bat
```

I guess, it somewhat depends on the called `anotherBatch.bat` if redirection works as intended (specifically input is line-by-line not single keystrokes). Note that `more` expects users to type lines, so the `pause` of your original script is omitted. If not handled by called `anotherBatch.bat`, users can terminate input by sending an EOF (by typing F6 or Control-Z in command window).